# Could anyone help me with this dart error?

Tags: sql-server, flutter, dart, spring-tool-suite

I'm making an application using flutter, on this specific screen, I list the animals registered in my bank, something I did isn't working, I imagine it's the images. can you help me?

the error:

```
Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "assets/images/ryan-parker-ucnZANGmyxM-unsplash.jpg")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#5d3fc(), name:
  "assets/images/ryan-parker-ucnZANGmyxM-unsplash.jpg", scale: 1)
DioException [bad response]: The request returned an invalid status code of 400.
DioException [bad response]: The request returned an invalid status code of 400.
Another exception was thrown: Vertical viewport was given unbounded width.
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1965:12
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1965:12
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1965:12
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1965:12
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1965:12
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1965:12
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1965:12
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1965:12
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1965:12
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1965:12
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1965:12
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1965:12
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1965:12
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1965:12
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1965:12
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1965:12
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1965:12
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1965:12
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1965:12
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1965:12
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1965:12
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1965:12
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1965:12
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1965:12
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1965:12
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1965:12
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1965:12
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1965:12
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1965:12
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1965:12
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1965:12
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1965:12
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1965:12
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1965:12
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1965:12
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1965:12
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1965:12
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1965:12
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1965:12
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1965:12
Another exception was thrown: Cannot hit test a render box that has never been laid out.
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/mouse_tracker.dart:205:12
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/mouse_tracker.dart:205:12
Another exception was thrown: Cannot hit test a render box that has never been laid out.
Another exception was thrown: Cannot hit test a render box that has never been laid out.
Another exception was thrown: Cannot hit test a render box that has never been laid out.
Another exception was thrown: Cannot hit test a render box that has never been laid out.
Another exception was thrown: Cannot hit test a render box that has never been laid out.
Another exception was thrown: Cannot hit test a render box that has never been laid out.
Another exception was thrown: Cannot hit test a render box that has never been laid out.
Another exception was thrown: Cannot hit test a render box that has never been laid out.
Another exception was thrown: Cannot hit test a render box that has never been laid out.
Another exception was thrown: Cannot hit test a render box that has never been laid out.
Another exception was thrown: Cannot hit test a render box that has never been laid out.
```

```
import '../models/animal_model.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_icon_button.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_util.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'catalog_controller.dart';
import 'catalog_model.dart';
export 'catalog_model.dart';

class CatalogWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const CatalogWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CatalogWidgetState createState() => _CatalogWidgetState();
}

class _CatalogWidgetState extends State<CatalogWidget> {
  late CatalogModel _model;
  List<AnimalModel> lista = List.empty(growable: true);
  final animaisController = CatalogController();

  final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _model = createModel(context, () => CatalogModel());

    listar();
  }

  Future<void> listar() async {
    lista = await animaisController.listarAnimais();

    setState(() {});

    print(lista);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _model.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var tam = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => _model.unfocusNode.canRequestFocus
          ? FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_model.unfocusNode)
          : FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
      child: Scaffold(
        key: scaffoldKey,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFF6A02F5),
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          actions: [
            FlutterFlowIconButton(
              borderColor: Color(0x0022282F),
              borderRadius: 20,
              borderWidth: 1,
              buttonSize: 70,
              fillColor: Color(0x00616161),
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.person,
                color: Color(0xFFFCBF08),
                size: 35,
              ),
              onPressed: () async {
                context.pushNamed('profile');
              },
            ),
          ],
          centerTitle: false,
          elevation: 0,
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          top: true,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: [
                ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                  child: Image.asset(
                    'assets/images/Captura_de_tela_2023-06-02_022508.jpg',
                    width: 419,
                    height: 127,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
                Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Conheça nossos animais',
                      style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).bodyMedium.override(
                            fontFamily: 'Outfit',
                            color: Color(0xFF1C1C1C),
                            fontSize: 20,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'clique em \"conhecer\" para ver ser direcionado ao whatsapp da ONG',
                      style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).bodyMedium.override(
                            fontFamily: 'Outfit',
                            color: Color(0xFF1C1C1C),
                            fontSize: 12,
                          ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SingleChildScrollView(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                          padding:
                              EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(10, 10, 10, 10),
                          child: ListView.builder(
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              itemCount: lista.length,
                              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                return Container(
                                  width: tam.width * 0.4,
                                  height: tam.height * .1,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Color(0xFC6D04FA),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                  ),
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                    children: [
                                      Align(
                                        alignment:
                                            AlignmentDirectional(-1.00, 0.00),
                                        child: Padding(
                                          padding:
                                              EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                                                  20, 0, 0, 0),
                                          child: Container(
                                            width: 120,
                                            height: 120,
                                            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                            ),
                                            child: Image.memory(
                                              lista
                                                  .elementAt(index)
                                                  .getFoto_animal,
                                              width: 10.0,
                                              height: 10.0,
                                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Padding(
                                        padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                                            0, 10, 0, 0),
                                        child: Column(
                                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                          children: [
                                            Text(
                                              lista
                                                  .elementAt(index)
                                                  .getNome
                                                  .toString(),
                                              style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(
                                                      context)
                                                  .bodyMedium
                                                  .override(
                                                    fontFamily: 'Outfit',
                                                    color: Color(0xFFFEBF03),
                                                    fontSize: 16,
                                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                  ),
                                            ),
                                            Text(
                                              lista
                                                  .elementAt(index)
                                                  .getSexo
                                                  .toString(),
                                              style:
                                                  FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                                      .bodyMedium
                                                      .override(
                                                        fontFamily: 'Outfit',
                                                        color:
                                                            Color(0xFFF3F4F5),
                                                      ),
                                            ),
                                            Text(
                                              lista
                                                  .elementAt(index)
                                                  .getIdade
                                                  .toString(),
                                              style:
                                                  FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                                      .bodyMedium
                                                      .override(
                                                        fontFamily: 'Outfit',
                                                        color:
                                                            Color(0xFFF3F4F5),
                                                      ),
                                            ),
                                            Text(
                                              lista
                                                  .elementAt(index)
                                                  .getPorte
                                                  .toString(),
                                              style:
                                                  FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                                      .bodyMedium
                                                      .override(
                                                        fontFamily: 'Outfit',
                                                        color:
                                                            Color(0xFFF3F4F5),
                                                      ),
                                            ),
                                            Text(
                                              lista
                                                  .elementAt(index)
                                                  .getDescricao
                                                  .toString(),
                                              style:
                                                  FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                                      .bodyMedium
                                                      .override(
                                                        fontFamily: 'Outfit',
                                                        color:
                                                            Color(0xFFF3F4F5),
                                                      ),
                                            ),
                                            Text(
                                              lista
                                                  .elementAt(index)
                                                  .getCastrado
                                                  .toString(),
                                              style:
                                                  FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                                      .bodyMedium
                                                      .override(
                                                        fontFamily: 'Outfit',
                                                        color:
                                                            Color(0xFFF3F4F5),
                                                      ),
                                            ),
                                            Padding(
                                              padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional
                                                  .fromSTEB(0, 5, 0, 0),
                                              child: FFButtonWidget(
                                                onPressed: () {
                                                  print('Button pressed ...');
                                                },
                                                text: 'Conhecer',
                                                options: FFButtonOptions(
                                                  height: 14,
                                                  padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional
                                                      .fromSTEB(24, 0, 24, 0),
                                                  iconPadding:
                                                      EdgeInsetsDirectional
                                                          .fromSTEB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                                                  color: Color(0xFF31EF41),
                                                  textStyle: FlutterFlowTheme
                                                          .of(context)
                                                      .titleSmall
                                                      .override(
                                                        fontFamily: 'Outfit',
                                                        color: Colors.white,
                                                      ),
                                                  elevation: 3,
                                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                                    color: Colors.transparent,
                                                    width: 1,
                                                  ),
                                                  borderRadius:
                                                      BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                );
                              })),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm trying to list the animals with their fields but when I execute, the screen is blank, with only the navbar appearing

Comment: This appears to be FlutterFlow specific.  You might want to use their support services rather than SO... FF is a commercial offering.

Answer (score 0):

first step:

Add this lines on pupspec.yaml

```
flutter: 

 assets:
    - assets/images/ryan-parker-ucnZANGmyxM-unsplash.jpg
    - .....
```

second step:

```
flutter clean
```

third step:

```
flutter pub get
```